# Error Code: 1064, Error Syntax to use near WITH

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de Crear una tabla pero en la creación de esta me aparecer un error al momento de llegar al "With", me marca Missing ')' pero todos cierran correctamente, les dejo la tabla.

````
    Idord       int             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Idcio       int             NOT NULL,
    Fecord      datetime        NOT NULL,
    Idclio      int             NOT NULL,
    Tipord      nvarchar(12)    NOT NULL,
    compra      nvarchar(50)    NOT NULL,
    Fecpro      datetime        NOT NULL,
    Staoc       int             NOT NULL,
    Instruc     nvarchar(250)   NOT NULL,
    hhin        int             NOT NULL,
    hhfi        int             NOT NULL,
    autor       nvarchar(50)    NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Agenda PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    Idord ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON PRIMARY
) ON PRIMARY;```


Estoy corriéndolo en MySQL 8.0.
````

Answer (score 0):

si estas usando MySQL tendrías que cambiar un poco la forma de crear la tabla, por que hay sintaxis que es de SQL-Server:

```
 CREATE TABLE `NombreTabla` (
     Idord       int             NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     Idcio       int             NOT NULL,
     Fecord      datetime        NOT NULL,
     Idclio      int             NOT NULL,
     Tipord      varchar(12)    NOT NULL,
     compra      varchar(50)    NOT NULL,
     Fecpro      datetime        NOT NULL,
     Staoc       int             NOT NULL,
     Instruc     varchar(250)   NOT NULL,
     hhin        int             NOT NULL,
     hhfi        int             NOT NULL,
     autor       varchar(50)    NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Idord ASC)
 );
```

- PRIMARY KEY -> Le aplicamos la clave primaria al campo Idord.